# Writing Redux Actions and Reducers for an object containing an array of ids to other objects

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

I'm just getting started with Redux/Reactjs and I'm writing a web application that contains `user` and `group` objects on the server:

```
// example user
user = {
  name: 'joe bloggs',
  age: 30
};

// example group
group = {
  title: 'Main Group',
  members: [userid1, userid2...useridn]
};
```

I have a basic `user` and `group` reducer and I'm trying to write an `action` that fetches the `group` data from the server and a list of all the members. The members field is an array of ids which map to a particular `user`.

How do you structure `actions` and `reducers` to fetch objects like `group` so they can be displayed by react components? Would my react component need to call `group` and `user` actions to fetch the `group` followed by each `user` in the members array? This seems like a common pattern in most web applications but I can't find a `redux` example. Any help or pointers to existing code much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the following:

1. Add a unique ID to your users.
2. Make `members` inside `groups` an array of ids.
3. Change the react component so it receives members and groups.

When using the react-redux connector, you can do the following:

```
groups: state.groups.map((group) => ({...group, members: group.members.map((id) => state.user[id])})),
```

So the component will receive the groups with the users array, instead of their ids.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm really new to react/redux, can I ask what the ..., is doing before 'members'?

Comment: @CSharp it was a syntactic mistake. I fixed it.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense now.